# How to preserve newlines with "to_lang" Google Translate

Tags: ruby

I use [`to_lang`](https://github.com/jimmycuadra/to_lang) to translate text in Rails 3 application.
I noticed that it converts newlines to spaces.
What is the most appropriate approach to preserve the newlines in the original text?
I don't want to split the original text by `"\n"`, translate the parts, and then combine them again, since it will increase the number of requests.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested it with `:debug => :request`:

`{:key=>"--", :q=>"To prevent abuse, Google places limits on API requests.\nUsing a valid OAuth 2.0 token or API key allows you to exceed \nanonymous limits by connecting requests back to your project.", :target=>"ru"}`

and as you can see it's not the gem fault. So, `to_lang` can translate arrays too. And if you'll write something like `["one", "two", "three"].to_russian` it will be one request to the Google API.

UPDATE:

```
irb(main):001:0> str = "test1\ntest2\ntest3"
=> "test1\ntest2\ntest3"
irb(main):002:0> arr = str.split("\n")
=> ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
irb(main):003:0> str = arr.join("\n")
=> "test1\ntest2\ntest3"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got your idea. Do you suggest to split the original text by `"\n"`, and translate the resulting array ? If yes, how could I know then where to insert the `"\n"` ?

Comment: The result from translation is string rather than array. The `"\n"` should be inserted in that string somehow...

Comment: if you'll call `["One", "Two", "Three"].to_spanish` you'll get `["Uno", "Dos", "Tres"]`